# BigDecimal to String in java?

Tags: java, bigdecimal

My code is:

```
x=new BigDecimal(x.toString()+" "+(new BigDecimal(10).pow(1200)).toString());
```

I am trying to concat two bigdecimals after converting them to string and then convert them back to bigdecimal.I am doing so because x has a value with a decimal point and multiplying will change its value.It compiles fine but throws a numberformat exception on execution.

My idea was to use the BigDecimal("String x") constructor to convert the string back to BigDecimal.

Note:
(for example)
x=1333.212
and I am converting it to
x=1333.2120000

Comment: So if I understand, you want to take a number like `123.123` and turn it into `1230...0.123`, where there are 10^1200 zeros in that truncated portion?

Comment: That's still not what you want, because 10^1200 starts with a "1" which I suggest you don't want. It would really help if you'd give a *simple* example of input and expected output - with just (say) 4 digits in the input, and adding an extra 5.

Comment: @JonSkeet I never thought of that thank you very much I have edited the question asap.

Comment: Right. That's *much* easier to understand - and the `setScale()` part of my answer is what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's failing to parse because you've got a space in there for no particular reason. Look at the string it's trying to parse, and you'll see it's not a valid number.

If you're *just* trying to add extra trailing zeroes (your question is very unclear), you should change the scale instead:

```
x = x.setScale(x.scale() + 1200);
```

Simple example:

```
BigDecimal x = new BigDecimal("123.45");
x = x.setScale(x.scale() + 5);
System.out.println(x); // 123.4500000
```

If you were trying to multiply the value by a power of 10 (as your initial question suggested), there's a *much* simpler way of doing this, using [`movePointRight`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#movePointRight-int-):

```
x = x.movePointRight(1200);
```

From the docs:

> The `BigDecimal` returned by this call has value (`this` × 10n) and scale `max(this.scale()-n, 0)`.

Comment: I just want to add 1200 trailing zeros and I do not want to move the decimal point.

Comment: @user1613360: See my edit... your question is *still* badly worded though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to try in this way

```
BigDecimal result=new
           BigDecimal("1333.212123232432543534324243253563453423423242452543535")
                                     .multiply(new BigDecimal("10").pow(1200));
System.out.println(result);
```

For your Edit:

```
BigDecimal result=new 
          BigDecimal("1333.212123232432543534324243253563453423423242452543535")
                                       .multiply(new BigDecimal("10").pow(1200));
System.out.println(result.movePointRight(-1200));
```

Comment: It will change the value I just want to add 1200 trailing zeros without moving the decimal point.

Comment: @user1613360: That's not what your question says. You've said: "I am converting it to x = 1333.212... * 10^1200". What do you think that "* 10^1200" would do?

Comment: @user1613360: Your question *still* isn't clear, because you're still talking about multiplying x by 10^1200, which you don't actually want to do.

Comment: @user1613360 actually what are you going to do here? I got your question as you want to multiplying x by 10^1200

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera I am calculating the value of pi and using intermediate results will improve the speed and accuracy.